# MongoDB over a large data set query is very slow

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am doing a deep learning project in which I have a large number of dataset(almost 10 millions) in customer collection.  I am filtering with all the customer column as per requirement. Almost every filtered columns are string.  I can not put index on every column(35 columns) as this is not a good idea. There are some complex query as well like aggregation with group.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca35824a7ad6a17e9c6eeb7"),
    "batchId" : 1,
    "demographicsState" : "Minnesota",
    "demographicsGender" : "Female",
    "jobCount" : "0 to 6",
    "jobCreated" : "No",
    "callResolution" : "No",
    "customerEffortScore" : 2,
    "phoneAccessibility" : "90 to 100",
    "callRepTime" : "Just right",
    "hadPriorCallsPastThirtyFiveDays" : "Yes",
    "autoDebitFlag" : "No",
    "servcoName" : "Monitronics",
    "demographicsAge" : "45 to 54",
    "checkedWebsiteFirst" : "No",
    "alarmRelated" : "12-Sensor",
    "reasonPrimary" : "19-Alarm, system or equipment related reason",
    "inInitialTerm" : "Yes",
    "callDuration" : "10 to 19",
    "siteKind" : "Residential",
    "customerSiteTenureDays" : "326",
    "highRisk" : "No",
    "monthsLeftUntilContractRenewal" : "26",
    "nielsen" : "Savvy suburbs",
    "callReason" : "Customer tech support",
    "serviceScheduled" : "-",
    "hadPriorCallsPastFiveDays" : "Yes",
    "dropped" : "No",
    "serviceResolution" : "80 to 89",
    "dept" : 190,
    "serviceRepresentative" : "90 to 100",
    "demographicsIncome" : "50,000 - 74,999",
    "aarpMember" : "No",
    "rmr" : 44.99,
    "satisfactionOverall" : 9,
    "dropYes" : 1,
    "dropNo" : 0,
    "cltv" : 4146.578333333334
}
```

Here is my query that I require to get data:

```
db.customers.aggregate(
            [{$match:[
                    {$and:[
                        {"demographicsState": "Minnesota"},
                        {"demographicsGender": "Female"},
                        {"jobCount": "0 to 6"},
                        {"jobCreated":"Yes"},
                        {"callResolution": "No"},
                        {"customerEffortScore": {"$gt":0 "$lt": 8}},
                        {"phoneAccessibility": "50 to 60"},
                        {"hadPriorCallsPastThirtyFiveDays": "No"},
                        {"autoDebitFlag": "Yes"},
                        {"alarmRelated": "10-Sensor"},
                        {"callDuration": "20 to 29"},
                        {"hadPriorCallsPastFiveDays": "Yes"},
                        {"demographicsIncome":"50,000-74,999"},
                        {"aarpMember": "Yes"},
                        {"rmr": {"$gt": 30 $lt: 50 }},
                        {"dropYes":1}
                    ]
            },
            {"$group":{"_id": "$demographicsGender", "count":{"$sum":1} }}]}])
```

I am filtering and group by with every column in above schema of customer table. Please let me know, If anybody have any idea.

Comment: You are also lacking any code showing exactly what you are doing. *"..as per requirement..."* is nowhere near as descriptive as actual code and some idea of how many expected results need to come from this 10 million collection. Having "indexes on every field" is certainly not an answer, and it's probably more about the process you are actually doing and what fields are actually important to that. Needs code.

Comment: Yes I already read that in your question and I said the same myself. Means nothing. Your question is extremely unclear without **sample code** to show what the query you are issuing actually is. This is actually a prompt to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55570860/edit). Please don't attempt to post code within "comments" and **edit the question** instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn Just edit the Question, Please check.

Comment: So which part is "slow"? Is it the actual `$match` or the execution of the `$group`? You can simply test the same "query" conditions ( which are the `$match` part ) with a regular find. And even apply the `explain()` option to see what the query planner has to say. I suspect the actual "slowness" is mostly because of the `$group`, and if the `$match` still returns **a lot of documents**, then the `$group` is basically the "brute force" part that needs to churn all that data. Most likely your system implementation  is just not up to the task for how much data is being thrown at it.

Comment: Basically, you have some research to do. The `$match` part can be fixed with indexes, but the rest is really outside of the scope of what answers here can tell you. Other than to "get a bigger boat", which is actually more capable of handling the load you want to give it.